# How to define User/Permission relationship as M:M?

Tags: erd, many-to-many

The `Resource` relates to `Action` as **M**:**M** via `Permission` join table/separate entity. User can have many permissions. The same permission may be assigned to multiple users.

How to define `User`-`Permission` relation as **M**:**M**? How would it look like in **EF**?

[image: erd diagramm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea - should there be a terenary relationship in there?  There seems to be a three way relationship between the resource, permission and the user.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a ternary relationship.

Comment: Just don't know how to deal with (join) tables?

Comment: Can you show the tables in logical form?  there are not fks there.  Did you add in the terenary relationship.  If normalised properly the JOIN query should be simple.